# Setting variable in ModelBuilder to change across several different steps with one edit

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a series of counties I need to update some information for. I have four tables, each with the FIPS# at the end of the table (a dbf). For example:
1. TabA007
2. TabB007
3. TabC007
4. TabD007

These tables get joined to a layer and a field calculator tool is used to grab the field values. There are roughly 25 steps in this whole process, and when I move on to a new county (say, 008), I have to change the 007 to 008 in every step, sometimes twice in the step.

For example, joined field "TableA007.FieldName007" now needs to become "TableA008.FieldName008". Setting the different steps as parameters doesn't work for a number of reasons, one being that each join needs to be indexed before it can move on. This tool has only worked in Edit mode.

Is there a way to tell the model to make anything that is of one number into another?

Here's some code with one table and one process (the one I am trying to work has 4 tables, 4 joins, and twenty field calculations...simple but elaborate)

workspace = r"C:\Users\cJones\OneDrive - ABC\Documents\NRCS_SoilsMaster\NY115\spatial"

## Local variables

soilmu_a_ny115 = "soilmu_a_ny115.SHP"

HYD115_DBF = "C:\Users\cJones\OneDrive - ABC\Documents\HYD115.DBF"

arcpy.AddIndex_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "AREASYMBOL;SPATIALVER;MUSYM;MUKEY", "", "NON_UNIQUE", "NON_ASCENDING")

## Process: Add Join

arcpy.AddJoin_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "MUSYM", HYD115_DBF, "MUSYM", "KEEP_ALL")

## Process: Add Attribute Index

arcpy.AddIndex_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "AREASYMBOL;SPATIALVER;MUSYM;MUKEY;Hydric;FARMLNDCL;SlopeLow;SlopeRep;SlopeHIgh;KFFact;HYDGRP", "", "NON_UNIQUE", "NON_ASCENDING")

arcpy.AddJoin_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "MUSYM", HYD115_DBF, "MUSYM", "KEEP_ALL")

## Process: Select Layer By Attribute

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"HYD115.LSEQ\" IS NOT NULL")

## Process: Calculate Field

arcpy.CalculateField_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "Hydric", "\"yes\"", "VB", "")

## Process: Select Layer By Attribute (2)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"HYD115.LSEQ\" IS NULL")

## Process: Calculate Field (2)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "Hydric", "\"no\"", "VB", "")

## Process: Select Layer By Attribute (3)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "CLEAR_SELECTION", "")

## Process: Remove Join

arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(soilmu_a_ny115, "")

All the tables have the same name aside from the FIPS number.

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.

Comment: I have often found modelbuilder fails to run as expected under this scenario of making and breaking joins because parameters seem to hang on to previous values/settings. Thinks like field maps are a nightmare and never work! If this was me I would move to a python scripting environment where you have _total control_ of parameter settings over complex loops. You are calling all the same tools just in a scripting environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have moved to a scripting environment but am getting this error:
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
The value cannot be a feature class
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.

Comment: Can't really comment without seeing the code, suggest you amend your question and include the code?